# Dropdown menu with css not working

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navbar

I am facing some problem with this drop down menu thing. I read your article and it helped me. In the beginning, the drop down worked but when I added some more styling then it stopped working. Other divs and navigation bar is working fine but the drop down menu is not working. Can you please help me pointing out what should be corrected here?

```
The parent div is nav-bar-left and the style is
.nav-bar-left {
float; left;
overflow: hidden;
width: 980px;
height: 26px;
background-color: Lavender;
border: 1px solid MidnightBlue;
border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
}
The navigation div is #horizontalmenu which resides within the above parent div and the style is
#horizontalmenu {
width: 733px;
margin: 0;
position: relative;
float: left;
padding: 0;
}
Rest of the styling for navigation bar is
#navbar {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
width: 100%;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
display: inline-table;
height: 26px;
z-index: 5;
}
#navbar li {
float: left;
position: relative;
}
#navbar a:link, #navbar a:visited {
display: block;
color: #333;
background-color: lavender;
text-align: center;
padding: 6px 10px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: MidnightBlue;
border-width: 0 1px 0 0;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 14px;
}
#navbar a:hover, #navbar a:active {
color: #fff;
background-color: #6b0c36;
text-decoration: underline;
}
#navbar ul {
left:-9999px;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
}
#navbar ul li {
float:none;
border-style: solid;
border-color: Lavender;
border-width: 0 1px 1px 1px;
}
#navbar ul a {
white-space: nowrap;
}
#navbar li:hover ul {
left: 0;
}
#navbar:hover a {
text-decoration: none;
}
#navbar li:hover ul a {
text-decoration: none;
background-color: Lavender;
color: #333;
}
#navbar li:hover ul li a:hover {
background-color: Lavender;
color: #333;
}
```

So, why is it not working and what can be done?

Comment: can you please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ file

Answer (score 0):

I found this menu CSS one of my best collection for dropdown menu:

> [Create a Multilevel Dropdown menu with CSS and improve it via jQuery](http://www.kriesi.at/archives/create-a-multilevel-dropdown-menu-with-css-and-improve-it-via-jquery)

And you can find a backup of those codes [here in my pastebin](http://pastebin.com/uiNKx7LM).

Comment: I visited your link. There I see you added both position: absolute and position: relative for same selector #nav ul. #nav, #nav ul{
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
     list-style-type:none;
     list-style-position:outside;
     position:relative;
     line-height:1.5em;
 } and then again #nav ul {
    position:absolute;
    width:12em;
    top:1.5em;
    display:none;
}. Is it ok?